# How to add preprocessor definition on visual studio 2017 c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

How to modify preprocessor definition in Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: There is no such thing as "the preprocessor definition" - please make your question much clearer. Also, you are not going to learn C++ from online tutorials - get a good textbook.

Comment: @NeilButterworth There is something called preprocessor definitions in VS apparently.

Comment: Are you asking about #defines available to the preprocessor?

Comment: Don't learn C++ from online tutorials. Most, if not all, are very bad and teach a lot of bad things. Instead, get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/9254539).

Comment: @NeilButterworth There is literally a "Preprocessor definitions" property.

Comment: @VTT Yes, I know, but there is no single  "the preprocessor definition"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Visual Studio, the Preprocessor Definitions can be modified on a per-project basis by right-clicking on the project within the Solution Explorer, then selecting Properties.  Then, expand the "C/C++" selection in the tree, and you will see Preprocessor as a category.

Comment: Actually it can be modified on per-translation unit basis.